# firebase pod was installed less version than the latest version exists

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I try to install the latest version of **Firebase pod**. I know that the latest version of this pod is **4.1.1** from cocoa pods official site https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase

But when I call **pod update** command from iOS terminal, I see that this pod was installed as 3.17.0.

This is what I see in iOS terminal after **pod update** command execution:

```
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.5.0)
Using Bolts (1.8.4)
Using Crashlytics (3.8.5)
Using Digits (3.0.2)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.26.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.26.0)
Using FBSDKMessengerShareKit (1.3.2)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.26.0)
Using Fabric (1.6.12)
Using Firebase (3.17.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.9.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (3.1.1)
Using FirebaseCore (3.6.0)
Using FirebaseCrash (1.1.6)
Using FirebaseDatabase (3.1.2)
Using FirebaseDynamicLinks (1.4.0)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.10)
Using FirebaseInvites (1.3.0)
Using FirebaseMessaging (1.2.3)
Using FirebaseStorage (1.1.0)
Using FirebaseUI (4.1.1)
Using GTMOAuth2 (1.1.4)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.11)
Using Google (3.1.0)
Using GoogleAPIClientForREST (1.3.0)
Using GoogleSignIn (4.0.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
Using IQKeyboardManagerSwift (4.0.13)
Using MBProgressHUD (1.0.0)
Using Protobuf (3.4.0)
Using SwiftyStoreKit (0.10.7)
Using TwitterCore (3.0.0)
Using TwitterKit (3.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 23 dependencies from the Podfile and 33 total pods installed.
```

This is content of my **Podfile** in project:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'PrayerDeck' do
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Database'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Digits'
pod 'TwitterCore'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'Firebase/Invites'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'
end

target 'PrayerDeckTests' do

end

target 'PrayerDeckUITests' do

end
```

**UPDATE:**

When I try to update **Podfile** and set more specific version like this **pod 'Firebase', '~> 4.0'** I get next error in iOS terminal:

```
- `FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.0.3)` required by `Firebase/Core (4.1.1)`
- `FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.2)` required by `Google/Core (3.0.3)`
- `GoogleSignIn (~> 3.0)` required by `Google/SignIn (2.0.4)`
- `GoogleSignIn (~> 4.0)` required by `FirebaseInvites (2.0.1)`
- `Firebase/Invites` required by `Podfile`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Podfile is using the deprecated 'Google/SignIn' which forces the Firebase 3.x dependencies.

Change it to

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

Comment: Thank you! I have done it but after pod update execution I get next error:   [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.0.2)` required by `Firebase/Core (4.0.4)`
- `FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.2)` required by `Google/Core (3.0.3)`
- `GoogleSignIn` required by `Podfile`
- `GoogleSignIn (~> 3.0)` required by `Google/SignIn (2.0.4)`
- `GoogleSignIn (~> 4.0)` required by `FirebaseInvites (2.0.0)`
- `Firebase/Invites` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Invites` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Comment: Based on the message, it looks like Google/SignIn is still there

Comment: Thank you! It was my mistake. Change pod 'Google/SignIn' to pod 'GoogleSignIn' helps me! :)

Comment: Could you say how did you understand that I should use pod 'GoogleSignIn' (not 'Google/SignIn' ) and that it requires Firebase 3.x? I ask you for future. Because a spent much time to try decide this problem byself. Thank you one more time! )

Comment: CocoaPods prints "[!] Google has been deprecated"

Comment: Shame on me! Thank you! :)